# Django rest framework - filtering for serializer field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have question about Django REST-full framework.

When products have rendered into remote client, each of product takes a filed with filtered data.

For example, model may be like this.

```
 class Product(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField()

 class Like(models.Model):
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="likes")
```

On the client, each **likes** of product counted with true value, not false.

So I tried with below code in the serializer.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    likes = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Like.objects.filter(whether_like=True))

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'likes')
```

But, that is not working as I wanted.

What should I do?

The following is extra view code.

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def product_list(request, user_id, format=None):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 103, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_likes(self, product):
        qs = Like.objects.filter(whether_like=True, product=product)
        serializer = LikeSerializer(instance=qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'likes')
```

**`LikeSerializer` omitted for brevity.

Comment: And.. where can I see a additional reference for this?

Comment: Current recommendation is the remove the `'get_likes'` argument to `SerializerMethodField()` since `get_foo()` is default naming for field `foo`.

Answer (score 42):

Instead of `SerializerMethodField`, which causes one additional database query per object, you can now (starting with Django 1.7) use [`Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) objects in the queryset of your DRF `ViewSet`:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch(
        'likes',
        queryset=Like.objects.filter(like=True)))
```

The prefetch needs just one query, ensuring vastly superior performance compared to `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for solution to this exact problem for couple days now.

Comment: The `prefetch_related(Prefetch(...))` hint is a life-saver! I didn't know we could use `Prefetch()` to make custom filter on the prefetch itself, what a good thing! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: How can you use `prefetch_related()` to add the additional likes field to your model?  When I tried it, it threw an error along the lines of `Cannot find 'likes' on Product object, 'likes' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()`