# How to create another column with filtered value in queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a query that retrieves 20 questions. The query then should add another column or data to the queryset that indicates which choice the user has answered. So in total there are 4 models, including a User model.

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_votes     = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question    = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    vote_count  = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Voting(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice  = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Query**

```
Question.objects.filter(
        Q(user=3))[:20]
```

When I do this, it doesn't work:

```
Question.objects.filter(Q(user=1)).annotate(which_answer= filter(choice__question=3, user=1))[:20]
```

I get `TypeError: filter() does not take keyword arguments`

How do I add another column in this query to show which choice the user picked?

Comment: Check out aggregates and annotations https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/

Comment: @Victor'Chris'Cabral Hmm this is aggregating though. I don't want to aggregate. I want to actually retrieve which choice id the user answered. I'm trying this query: `Question.objects.filter(Q(user=1)).annotate(which_answer= filter(choice__question=3, user=1))` but it is not working

Comment: @user2896120 what is the SQL query you want?  Let's start there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotation would need to look something like this (if user id = 1):

```
choice_query = Subquery(Choice.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk')).values('choice')[:1], output_field=models.CharField())

Question.objects.filter(user=1).annotate(which_answer=choice_query)[:20]
```

You write a subquery that filters the choice objects based on which question is being annotated and the user, selects just 1 (assuming theres only supposed to be 1) and outputs that choice value to a char field, then you annotate with that subquery.

just a sidenote: that Q expression seems unneeded here.

Not sure what you're use case here is exactly, but you also might see more luck  or better performance if you're using serializers and just add a select related clause to your main query and don't bother with the annotation.

Edit: after discussion, I believe what you actually want is the user's VOTE, which points at their choice. It would look like this (again user id = 1):

```
vote_query = Subquery(Vote.objects.filter(question=OuterRef('pk'), user=1).values('choice')[:1], output_field=models.IntegerField())

Question.objects.filter(user=1).annotate(which_answer=vote_query)[:20]
```

This query will output the id of the users selected choice to the which_answer annotation.

Comment: Hmm, how would I do it with a serializer? I thought first I had to filter the query for the serializer to use?

Comment: I'm really only familiar with the serializers in django rest framework, but they automatically fetch related infomration so long as you declare the relationship in your model serializer. Just make sure to prefetch / select related otherwise it's a preformance killer. If you try it out with serializers but can't get it, just post another question and link me to it.

Comment: Yes I am using the Django REST framework. However, how would I show which choice the logged in user selected?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309507/django-rest-framework-filtering-for-serializer-field

Comment: also did my answer work for your original question re annotating? I didn't test it but i've written very similar queries that work fine.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: choice, id, question, question_id, vote_count, voting`

Comment: Also, here's the question I just asked in regard for REST: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403329/creating-serializer-to-display-correct-data

Comment: Ok then your issue is that your choice model doesn’t actually have a user field. That’s an error in your data modeling

Comment: `choice` shouldn't have a user field though. Each choice has a question id, and we can know who wrote the question by the question's user id

Comment: Ok then you remove the clause to filter the choice by user? I updated my answer. It’s very unclear what you’re exactly after here.

Comment: Yes this works. Basically what I'm trying to do is this: I have a polls app. There are questions with choices. If a person went to a question they've already answered, then it shouldn't let the user answer that question, instead it should show the user which choice they've selected when they did answer it. That's what I'm trying to retrieve in REST.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting the id of the incorrect user selected choice when I replace `choice` with `id`

Comment: Ok, i see what you're after now. you're kind of looking at it wrong, what you actually want is the vote, not the choice, I can fix the query in my answer if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out when I get home. Is this the best way to do something like this as far as REST?

Comment: this is a good method and you won't run into performance problems with it, but what's "best" comes down to your specific use case and also your philosophical views on coding. You have a requirement: show a user a list of questions and show them either what they've chosen or the available choices.  You can accomplish this in many ways, you could do it this way and figure out on the server via SQL annotations, could do it via the serializer, or you could've exposed a questions endpoint and a votes endpoint and combined them on the client.  Really comes down to preference and needs.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you so much for the advice :)