# Creating serializer to display correct data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I have 4 models. `User`, `Question`, `Choice`, and `Voting`. This is basically a polls app I'm trying to create. A question can have many choices. The `Voting` model tracks what each user chose as their answer.

What I'd like to do is retrieve all the questions and also check what choice the logged in user selected for each question. Here's the models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    total_votes     = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Choice(models.Model):
    question    = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    vote_count  = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Voting(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice  = models.ForeignKey(Choice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Here's how I want the data displayed:

```
{
    user: 2
    status: "Hello"
    total_votes: 101
    choices: [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "choice": "first choice",
                    "vote_count": 31,
                    "question": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "choice": "second choice",
                    "vote_count": 70,
                    "question": 3
                }
            ],
    choice_selected: 2
}
```

In the data above, the logged in user selected choice 2 in this specific question.

**Edit: My attempt to add serializer, but displays Object of type 'Voting' is not JSON serializable**

```
class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'

class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(source='choice_set', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'


class GetProfileQuestions(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.all()
```

This query successfully prints out each question and its choices. However, how do I make it so that it also prints out which choice the user selected for each question?

```
class VotingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Voting
        fields = '__all__'    


class ChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    votes = VotingSerializer(source='voting_set', many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = '__all__'


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = ChoiceSerializer(source='choice_set', many=True)
    choice_selected = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_choice_selected(self, obj):
        choice_selected = Voting.objects.filter(choice__question=obj.id).filter(user=obj.user)
        return choice_selected
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want this in your QuestionSerializer class

```
 choice_selected = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
```

and define a method that looks something like this in QuestionSerializer …

```
def get_choice_selected(self, obj):
        choice_selected = Voting.objects.filter(choice__question=obj.id).filter(user=obj.user)
        return choice_selected
```

The above is untested.

Comment: Hmm, I am getting this error: `Object of type 'Voting' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Add a serializer for it then.

Comment: How would you do it in this situation? I am not too familiar with functions inside serializers

Comment: I would add a serializer class like you have for `ChoiceSerializer` but the class name would be `VotingSerializer` and it would have `Model = Voting`

Comment: Hmm, I did that but I am getting the same error. I added what I did in my question please take a look at the edits see if I'm doing it correctly?

Comment: Sorry, not receiving the same error anymore. For some reason my server wasnt updating correctly. However, I'm not getting anything in choice_selected. The value is empty when it shouldn't be empty

Comment: Well I don't have your data or your code. You'll have to hammer out the query in `get_choice_selected` but I am pretty certain the solution to your question is a `SerializerMethodField`.

Comment: When I do the same exact query in terminal, I get a result though...Also the format the data is shown is not the format I want it. The voting is nested inside choices. Can't it be outside of choices?