# How to filter a reverse related field without additional queries?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-filter

How can I filter the reverse relation queryset generated by a **`ModelViewSet`** **without** causing an additional **n** queries?

### MRE:

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    image_url = models.URLField()

class Item(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='items',  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py:

```
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('items').all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

serializers.py:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

filters.py:

```
import django_filters as filters

class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    price = filters.RangeFilter(field_name='items__price')
    quantity = filters.RangeFilter(field_name='items__quantity')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = {
            'name': ['icontains'],
        }
```

Filtering on the `Product` model's fields works fine, but the `items` reverse relation ignores the filtering completely.

I found a "solution" from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28310334/10746224); ie. do the filtering via a `SerializerMethodField`:

```
item_fieldset = {'price', 'quantity'}

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_items')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_items(self, product):
        params = self.context['request'].query_params
        filter_fields = item_fieldset.intersection(set(params))
        filters = {field: params.get(field) for field in filter_fields}
        serializer = ItemSerializer(instance=product.items.filter(**filters), many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

But this cripples the performance of my app.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tested setting the `related_name` option - with "items" as value - in the `ForeignKey`?

Comment: @Rfroes87 yes, the related_name is set in my actual models.  I updated the example to include it.

Comment: you need to add `price` and `quantity` in the fields attribute of your `ProductFilter.Meta` class.

Comment: @alamshafi2263 `Meta.fields` is only a shortcut to include a model's fields, and is not used to "declare" the fields a filter should use.  Doing so results in `TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: price`

Comment: Can you please clarify which one you're expecting from the filter - if `price_min = 10` is supplied you want products with `item__price__gte=10` (this would include all items of the product irrespective of their `price_min`) or you want your filter to return queryset with product and only the items which are `item__price__gte=10`?

Comment: @alamshafi2263 the latter.

Comment: The latter is not possible with filters. Django ORM only filters on the Model you call and will return the objects of the Model you called. It will run filtering on related field only to identify original Model objects, won't filter the related objects. You might want to look towards writing some raw SQL for that purpose. Otherwise, the solution you found is the way.